# Upload de arquivo/parametros por HTTP em Java

Tags: java, python

Eu estava utilizando Python para atualizar aguns equipamentos via Post, onde eu definia alguns parâmetros e enviava um arquivo, onde o próprio equipamento se atualiza após receber este arquivo. Porém, como desenvolvi uma aplicação em Java com Swing, eu não consegui implementar o envio do arquivo e os parâmetros com as bibliotecas que encontrei.

Este é o código que utilizo para enviar os parâmetros e arquivo para o equipamento:

```
def Post(host,user, password, (param), files):
    url = 'http://'+host+'/cgi-bin/firmware.cgi'

    session = requests.session()
    ses = session.get(url)
    req1 = session.post(url, data = ({'formNumber' : '201', 'user' : user,    'password' : password}))
    req2 = session.post(url, files=files, data=param)
    print req2.content
    print session.cookies
```

Alguém sabe me informar como eu poderia fazer isto no Java?

Editado:

Consegui realizar o envio do arquivo via Post no java, porém, encontrei outro problema. Quando envio o arquivo, após o terminino do envio, o dispositivo é reiniciado, ou seja, não tenho nenhuma confirmação de que o arquivo foi enviado por completo ou não.

Existe alguma forma de checar se o arquivo foi enviado por completo?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

public class PostFunction {

    private static final String FORM_NUMBER_LOGIN = "201";
    private static final String FORM_NUMBER_UPDATE_FIRMWARE = "101";

    private String user;
    private String password;
    private String url;

    private HttpClient client;
    static int result;
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(PostFunction.class.getName());

    public PostFunction(final String url, final String user, final String password) {
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;
        this.url = url;
        this.client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Metodo para fazer atualizacao de firmware do equipamento.
     * 
     * @param file
     *            Arquivo de Firmware
     * @return Resposta de confirmacao
     */
    public Boolean updateFirmware(File file) {

        try {
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "loginPost INIT");
            this.loginPost();
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "loginPost END");

            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "sendFilePost INIT");
            this.sendFilePost(file);
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "sendFilePost END");

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }

    private void sendFilePost(File file) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        try {
            HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create().addTextBody("formNumber", FORM_NUMBER_UPDATE_FIRMWARE)
                    .addBinaryBody("btnBrowse", file, ContentType.create("application/octet-stream"), file.getName())
                    .build();

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            httpPost.setEntity(entity);

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
            System.out.println(response);

            InputStream body = response.getEntity().getContent();

            String outResponse = getStringFromInputStream(body);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void loginPost() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        try {

            int count = 0;

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(this.url);
            // add header
            httpPost.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");

            List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", user));
            urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("formNumber", FORM_NUMBER_LOGIN));

            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);

            InputStream body = response.getEntity().getContent();

            String outResponse = getStringFromInputStream(body);
            if (outResponse.contains("login")) {
                this.loginPost();
                LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Tentativa" + count++);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "LOGOU!");

    }

    private static String getStringFromInputStream(InputStream is) {

        BufferedReader br = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        result = 0;
        try {

            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                // sb.append(line.trim());
                System.out.println(line);
                if (line.trim().equals("id                          = setTimeout( \"start()\", 1000 );")) {
                    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Update OK");
                    result = 1;
                    break;
                }

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return sb.toString();

    }

    int resulting() {
        return result;

    }


}
```

Comment: Este é o stack em português, traduza sua pergunta.

Comment: Desculpe amigo, traduzido.

Comment: Cara, fazer esse tipo de conversão entre linguagem sai um pouco do escopo do site, não tem um jeito unico de fazer isso, alem de, sendo por aplicação desktop, envolver muita coisa que pode tornar uma resposta extensa demais.

Comment: @diegofm amigo, poderias ter ajudado com algum exemplo em java de envio de um arquivo qualquer utilizando algum metodo de sua escolha. Coloquei o código no meu post original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Galera, consegui atribuir o timeout na sessão quando o mesmo termina de enviar o arquivo, ou se demora muito a realizar a conexão. Tive que adicionar as configurações do HttpClientBuilder.

Segue código funcionando

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.conn.HttpClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class PostFunction {

    private static final String FORM_NUMBER_LOGIN = "201";
    private static final String FORM_NUMBER_UPDATE_FIRMWARE = "101";

    private String user;
    private String password;
    private String url;

    private CloseableHttpClient client;
    static int result;
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(PostFunction.class.getName());

    public PostFunction(final String url, final String user, final String password) {
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;
        this.url = url;

        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
        cm.setMaxTotal(128);
        cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(24);
        RequestConfig.Builder requestBuilder = RequestConfig.custom();
        requestBuilder = requestBuilder.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        requestBuilder = requestBuilder.setSocketTimeout(5000);

        HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
        builder.setDefaultRequestConfig(requestBuilder.build());
        builder.setConnectionManager(cm);
        this.client = builder.build();

    }

    /**
     * 
     * Metodo para fazer atualizacao de firmware do equipamento.
     * 
     * @param file
     *            Arquivo de Firmware
     * @return Resposta de confirmacao
     */
    public Boolean updateFirmware(File file) {

        try {
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "loginPost INIT");
            this.loginPost();
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "loginPost END");

            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "sendFilePost INIT");
            this.sendFilePost(file);
            LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "sendFilePost END");

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }

    private void sendFilePost(File file) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "antes entity");
        HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create().addTextBody("formNumber", FORM_NUMBER_UPDATE_FIRMWARE)
                .addBinaryBody("btnBrowse", file, ContentType.create("application/octet-stream"), file.getName())
                .build();
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "depois entity");
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "antes httppost entity");
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "depois httppost entity");

        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "antes httpResponse entity");
     try{
        client.execute(httpPost);
     }catch(IOException e){
         System.out.println("Terminou de enviar arquivo, devido a timeout da sessão");
         result = 1;
      return;
     }
   // System.out.println(httpPost.isAborted());
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "depois httpResponse entity");
        //System.out.println(response);

    }

    private void loginPost() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        try {

            int count = 0;

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(this.url);
            // add header
            httpPost.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");

            List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", user));
            urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("formNumber", FORM_NUMBER_LOGIN));

            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);

            InputStream body = response.getEntity().getContent();

            String outResponse = getStringFromInputStream(body);
            if (outResponse.contains("login")) {
                this.loginPost();
                LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Tentativa" + count++);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "LOGOU!");

    }

    private static String getStringFromInputStream(InputStream is) {

        BufferedReader br = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        result = 0;
        try {

            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                // sb.append(line.trim());
                System.out.println(line);
                if (line.trim().equals("id                          = setTimeout( \"start()\", 1000 );")) {
                    LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Update OK");
                    result = 1;
                    break;
                }

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return sb.toString();

    }

    int resulting() {
        return result;

    }

    /*
     * public static void main(String[] args) {
     * 
     * CGIIntelbras cgiIntelbras = new
     * CGIIntelbras("http://192.168.7.49/cgi-bin/firmware.cgi", "admin",
     * "lockinet.");
     * 
     * cgiIntelbras.updateFirmware(new
     * File("/home/lu050023/Python_projects/Bandwidth/AP300-v1.1.5-ptbr.bin"));
     * }
     */
```

}